# How to display dynamic image with thymeleaf in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

My image folder is under the src/main/resources/static/assets/images/packageImage.I want to display all image from that folder with thymeleaf.
fixed data is coming out .but dynamic image display in not work well.
my coding is here.Let me fix that.

```
  <form class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">

         <div class="form-group m-b-10">
             <label class="control-label col-sm-3">Tour Package:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-3">
               <label class="control-label" th:text="${package.packageName}" ></label>
           </div>
        </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
           <img th:src="@{'../assets/images/packageImage/' + ${package.picture}}" class="img-responsive" />

     </div>
```

Comment: Are you sure the relative path to your images is correct? If the images aren't shown, you probably have some errors in the console of your browser, add those errors to your question.

Comment: Did you get this working? I'm working on something similar

Comment: My best guess is that like @g00glen00b suggested, it might be the relative path. I'm used something very much like the following and it worked:  <img th:src="@{${package.picture}}"  />